# Exempt one or more child element of a parent with layout directive

Tags: angular-material

It is possible to achieved something like this given code?

```
<div layout="column">
    <div>This is affected by layout column</div>
    <div>how to exempt this one from layout column?</div>
    <div>This is affected by layout column</div>
</div>
```

Im using `angular-material`

Comment: Hi @ShiftN'Tab I really didn't unterstand what you want, is something like tiles?

Comment: @LuizRossi no its not, dont over think it. im just asking if it is possible if we can exempt an element from a container with `layout="column"`. i mean an element that cannot be affected with layout directive despite a child of an element with layout directive..

Comment: Yes, I got it, but I'm sure about what effect do you want, cause directly you can't, what you can do is something like: 
`<div layout="column">
    <div>This is affected by layout column</div>
</div>
<div layout="row">
    <div>how to exempt this one from layout column?</div>
</div>
<div layout="column">
    <div>This is affected by layout column</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: maybe something like this `<div> <div>how to exempt this one from layout column?</div> </div>` i want to get rid of layout directive.. but sadly i have an application that is enclosed by a parent element with a layout directive and i want some elements not to get affected by it. the structure is like on my question but there is so many element that rely on layout directive and on the otherhand i want some element to get rid of it.